# zip file too large aws lambda java gradle

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-lambda

I would like to deploy my java function on aws lambda

I took this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html

This is my `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.61'
}

group 'com.xxx'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2"
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:2.2.7'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5.2'

    runtimeOnly 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.1.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main'
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': archiveVersion,
                'Main-Class': 'Main'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from sourceSets.main.output

    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}

task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    manifest {
        attributes (
                'Implementation-Title': 'AWS Handler',
                'Implementation-Version': archiveVersion,
                'Main-Class': 'AWSHandler'
        )
    }

    from compileJava
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

So I am running `gradle buildZip` to build my zip, my aws class implementing `RequestHandler` is in `src/main/java/AWSHandler.java`

Once the command ended with success I have a 710MB zip file, this is huge !!!
When I am unzipping the file I can see that there are many libs to support many os

[image]

Flowing this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html seems that java8 functions are running on `Amazon Linux`

So I could clean my zip to only get this os

Can I do it with gradle or should I create an extra script to clean my file ?

Comment: We can reduce the number of dependencies as explained here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Reducing-the-Number-of-Dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `into` method of the `Zip` task type can accept a `CopySpec` which you can use to add exclusions:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:into(java.lang.Object,%20org.gradle.api.Action)

```
into('lib') {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    exclude("**windows**") // example, untested.
}
```

See the Javadoc for more details: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html